# No output, just showing "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm setting up a new cursor from 3 tables and with looping inside the code. But after all day i tried, no error, no warning, but my out put just showing "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.", nothing else.

i tried to change my variable, SET SERVEROUTPUT ON, SET VERIFY OFF, etc, but it nothing show up, just like the first time i tried.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
V_PROD GD_INBAG%ROWTYPE;
V_OUT OUT_INBAG%ROWTYPE;
V_IN IN_INBAG%ROWTYPE;
V_NOMER NUMBER(8,0):=0;
CURSOR DATA_GUDANG IS
SELECT A.ID_PROD, A.NAMA_PROD, A.STOK_PROD, B.IN_PROD, C.OUT_PROD
FROM GD_INBAG A, IN_INBAG B, OUT_INBAG C
WHERE A.ID_PROD=B.ID_PROD AND A.ID_PROD=C.ID_PROD
ORDER BY A.ID_PROD;
BEGIN
OPEN DATA_GUDANG;
LOOP
FETCH DATA_GUDANG INTO V_PROD.ID_PROD, V_PROD.NAMA_PROD, `V_PROD.STOK_PROD, V_OUT.OUT_PROD, V_IN.IN_PROD;`
EXIT WHEN DATA_GUDANG%NOTFOUND;
V_NOMER :=V_NOMER+1;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NUMBER        : '||' '||V_NOMER);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PRODUCT ID    : '||' '||V_PROD.ID_PROD);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PRODUCT NAME  : '||' '||V_PROD.NAMA_PROD);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('STOCK         : '||' '||V_PROD.STOK_PROD);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('OUT PRODUCT   : '||' '||V_OUT.OUT_PROD);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('IN PRODUCT    : '||' '||V_IN.IN_PROD);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('=========================================================');
END LOOP;
CLOSE DATA_GUDANG;
END;
```

I expected the output of my code to be showing all data (number, ID, product name, stock, product in and out) based and ordered by ID_PROD.

Comment: SQL Developer has a separate window for DBMS_OUTPUT. You need to select menu View > DBMS_OUTPUT then open a tab for the connection you want to display. Have you done that?

Comment: Do you get dbms_output from any other PL/SQL code, or is the problem only with this specific code?

Comment: @APC where's that? I don't know about that, but, it just fine if i just code without relationships to other table, like making code to say "hello World" or etc.

Comment: @william No, i make some procedure and function that also required DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE, and it just fine, but when i try to make some cursor, it doesn't show up the out put

Comment: Then perhaps the cursor isn’t returning any rows.

Comment: @williamrobertson - my first thought was maybe the query doesn't return any data. But having moved back to SQL Developer after years of PL/SQL Developer I've been caught out a couple of times by its handling of DBMS_OUTPUT. It's not intuitive. So I agree, if DBMS_OUTPUT is working for other procedures the only option left is that this query returns no rows.

Comment: i dont know why, but if i include this procedure with package, it just fine. I also use inner join for checking my relation from one table to another, and i include that to my cursor, it doesn't work. But if i using Package, it running and show my output. i have no idea what happen in here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your cursor is not fetching any information.

Any data will be shown if below cursor will open else it not show any result
    OPEN DATA_GUDANG;
    LOOP
     FETCH DATA_GUDANG INTO V_PROD.ID_PROD, V_PROD.NAMA_PROD, 
     `V_PROD.STOK_PROD, V_OUT.OUT_PROD, V_IN.IN_PROD;`
     EXIT WHEN DATA_GUDANG%NOTFOUND;
    V_NOMER :=V_NOMER+1;

```
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NUMBER        : '||' '||V_NOMER);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PRODUCT ID    : '||' 
  '||V_PROD.ID_PROD);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PRODUCT NAME  : '||'. 
 '||V_PROD.NAMA_PROD);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('STOCK         : '||' 
 '||V_PROD.STOK_PROD);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('OUT PRODUCT   : '||' 
 '||V_OUT.OUT_PROD);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('IN PRODUCT    : '||' '||V_IN.IN_PROD);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE 
  ('=========================================================');
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE DATA_GUDANG;
END;
```